# WPF Create and show a new window inside a method and get its result

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Window` in WPF and I want to create and show a new instance of it in a method. It is a message box with *Yes* / *No* buttons.
But it seems like the method need to be "closed" to show my window. In this method are some other things which should be influenced by the control of this window.

```
private void MyNiceMethod()
{
    MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
    myWindow.Show();

    while (CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow)
    {//Wait}

    //The bool CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow is true usually.
    //And a Button on myWindow set the var to false, so the code in my method
    //continues
}
```

Is there a way to show a `Window`, before the method is "closed"?

Comment: I think you should explain more precisely what the actual problem is that you want to solve. Where is this method called? What is the `CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow` used for?

Comment: The method is called by a button click, and the CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow is a bool which value is set by a button click on myWindow. In my real Method, is more Code between "myWindow.Show()"; and "bool ye = CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow;"

Comment: Is this window meant to be a modal dialog, e.g. opended, blocking the UI and then closed again returning a result that you use in `CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow`?

Comment: Yes it is a custom messagebox with yes no buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a modal dialog, like a confirmation with *Yes* and *No*, use [`ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1).

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

It returns the `bool?` value (`true`, `false` or `null`) that you set to the [`DialogResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.dialogresult?view=netcore-3.1) property in your `MyWindow`. The default value is `false`.

```
private void MyNiceMethod()
{
    MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
    
    var result = myWindow.ShowDialog();
    CrazyVariableInfluencedBymyWindow = result.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, the window will not be shown, as the Dispatcher is busy executing your event handler. An endless loop there isn't a good idea. Instead, show the window and set up either a DispatcherTimer to periodically look for your weird variable, or, better yet, just use an event. That's what they're for.

Comment: But myWindow is not showed every time, only if an another condition is true.

Comment: You can attach an event handler within an `if` block as well.